# Keyboard macro to select current word

Tags: sas

I'm trying to create a hotkey in the Enhanced Editor which has the same effect as double clicking the left mouse button near a word.  That is, if the cursor is at the start of a word, within a word, or at the end of a word, that word is selected.

I can't figure out a fail safe way to do this with a keyboard macro.  The trouble is getting the cursor to a fixed position, say the end of a word, every time, for every word.

The best I've come up with always looks something like:

```
Move cursor to next word start
Move cursor to next word start
Move cursor to previous word start
Move cursor left
Move cursor left
Move cursor left
Move cursor to next word boundary
Extend selection to previous word start
```

Try executing this on various words:

```
These are the first words

This is a list
  first
  second
  third

  This is and indented list
    first indent
    second indent
    third indent

These are the last words
```

Any of the words ending a line cannot be highlighted.  To fix this, you might try reversing the `next` and `previous` commands.  But then you get similar problems in the other direction (i.e. words in certain locations cause problems). It is also not robust with short words.  It will highlight `is` but not `a`.  Yet if you remove the `move cursor left` lines, then small words like `is` aren't highlighted at all.

Other ideas tried include:

1. Inserting a character to create some kind of anchor point
2. Using the search function and/or regular expressions to somehow trick the cursor into a fixed position.

Has anyone already figured this out?  Do you have any other ideas?  Is there a command I've overlooked?

Comment: This is base SAS, right, not EG?

Comment: Sorry about that.  Yes, base SAS with the Enhanced Editor.